# CSS Grid Nesting causes Sub-grid to get blow-off the parent grid cell

Tags: css, nested, overflow, css-grid

I'm working on my personal website and I'm using CSS Grid for everything layout related. I'm trying to make my grid system be as flexible as possible to allow nesting (in case I really need that).

My problem is the following: I have a grid with 2 rows, each having 2 columns, respectively 3 columns. I'm trying to basically nest the same grid, within on of the 3 columns of the first one. I think because of too much gap, they get blow-off their parent.

[Preview of my nested grid overflowing the parent grid cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUBaT.png)

Code below:

```css
.grid {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 50px;
    }

.grid__col-12 { grid-column-end: span 12; }
.grid__col-4 { grid-column-end: span 4; }
.grid__col-3 { grid-column-end: span 3; }
.grid__col-6 { grid-column-end: span 6; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__col-6">hey</div>
        <div class="grid__col-6">hey</div>
        <div class="grid__col-4">hey</div>
        <div class="grid__col-4">hey</div>
        <div class="grid grid__col-4">
            <div class="grid__col-6">hey</div>
            <div class="grid__col-6">hey</div>
            <div class="grid__col-4">hey</div>
            <div class="grid__col-4">hey</div>
            <div class="grid__col-4">hey</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I really can't understand why this is happening, so would love some clarification.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: @Paulie_D The columns in the second grid are forcing it to be wider than the parent (column). It looks like their minimum width is not actually 0 as set in the minmax function.

Comment: More likely it's the grid gap you have on there.

Comment: Hey! Can you show us a picture of your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the second grid has overflowing `div` elements is because of your `grid-gap`. The browser prioritizes the `grid-gap` value over the `fr` units you have in place. Because of this, your browser always tries to make sure that you have `grid-gap: 50px`, *regardless of parent element (or screen) width*.

So if your screen width is (for example) 375px (iPhone 11 Pro size), the browser will do whatever it can to get that `grid-gap` of 50px, but you'll get issues with your `div` sizes since the browser is trying to find whatever space is left for your `div` elements. The amount of space you have left would be very minimal in this case, so you'll have to use `@media` queries to change how the grid functions at different screen widths... That is, if you're adamant on keeping the 50px `grid-gap`.

**Another solution would be to make your `grid-gap` a percentage.** That way, it'll be dynamic with whatever parent element (or screen) width that you have.

So to summarize, your nested grid doesn't have enough space for its `div` elements because the nested grid is already so small. The browser prioritizes `grid-gap: 50px` so there's no room left in that nested grid for the other columns.

Comment: It kinda makes sense when the column containing the secondary grid gets really small, but in my example, there's still plenty of space left (the columns only have the word "hey" which is short enough to accommodate them plus 50px gap). So that's why I really can't understand why this happens at a relatively big width.

Comment: If you use your browser's Inspect tool, you'll find out that the "hey" isn't what's taking up all the space. That's just the text. The actual `div` spans a much larger area than the size of the text "hey". You've actually shown this in your own image. If you look at the transparent boxes around the "hey"s in your image, those are the actual sizes of the `div` elements. And as you can see, they are all separated by 50px, even in your nested grid.